# getting rows by id from csv string

Tags: mysql, csv, syntax

I'm trying to get all rows from my table by their id (the IDs are auto incremented) by searching for the IDs.

I'm trying something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE something = 'yes' AND (csvstring)
```

Where csvstring is something like this: 4, 53, 34, 23

The problem is that I don't think that you can do that. 
I tried "WHERE id IN (csvstring)" because I was googling this but that didn't work

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE something='yes' AND id IN (4,53,34,23)
```

That doesn't work?  Edit:  Just tested it, it does work.

Comment: yeah that works. My bad. I stupidly didn't check the csv string that I was passing in.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that in `id IN (csvstring)` is because the query parses `csvstring` as a whole string  and not as a particular id. You want to have like this: `id IN (4, 53, 34, 23)` but the query sees it like this `id IN ('4, 53, 34, 23')`

Maybe **[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)** works for you.

Try some thing this,

```
SELECT... FROM... WHERE something='yes' AND id IN (4,53,34,23)
```